# Terminal 1 hour ahead of system time

Tags: manjaro, clock

My terminal is 1 hour in advance of the actual time (which is displayed correctly at the tray). The local time at the time of the command is actually 13:53, while UTC is 12:53
Im using ZSH on Manjaro:

```
timedatectl 
           Local time: Sat 2021-01-02 14:53:20 CET
       Universal time: Sat 2021-01-02 13:53:20 UTC
             RTC time: Sat 2021-01-02 13:53:20    
            Time zone: Europe/Prague (CET, +0100) 
System clock synchronized: no                         
          NTP service: inactive                   
      RTC in local TZ: no
```

[image]

Comment: Have you dual-booted into Windows recently? Microsoft has a nasty habit of updating the RTC to match the local timezone. Booting back to Linux does not correct it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it's not a habit. It's a legacy thing from the DOS era when no one moves their computers around the globe. Just change Windows to use UTC time and it'll be solved

Comment: Any way to fix the issue on Linux without making Windows use UTC time?

Comment: See that "RTC in local TZ" setting? if that were "yes" then you'd match Windows behaviour, tho i'm not 100% sure if that handles DST without NTP being active